# Adding button to cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a subclass of UITableCell and here is my code so far:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {            

        voteCount = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2, 10, 10, self.frame.size.height)];
        voteCount.text = @"24";
        [self.contentView addSubview:voteCount];         

        upVote = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/3, 0, 20 , self.frame.size.height)];
        upVote.titleLabel.text = @"vote";
        [self.contentView addSubview:upVote];

    }
    return self;
}
```

The label shows up but the button does not.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try Setting up the background color to button, and set the hardcoded X,Y, Width, Height parameters and see if it shows up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code..

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (self) {   

         //For UILabel
            voteCount = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2, 10, 10, self.frame.size.height)];
            voteCount.text = @"24";
            [self.contentView addSubview:voteCount]; 

        //For UIButton

        upVote = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [upVote addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [upVote setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        upVote.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 10.0, 60.0, 60.0);//set your coordinates
        [self.contentView addSubview:upVote];

        }
        return self;
    }
```

It will work..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `[UIButton +buttonWithType:]`.

You also need to use `[UIButton -setTitle:forState:]`, not just set the text of its `titleLabel`.

Comment: I've tried adding upVote = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; but it still doesn't show up

Comment: `[upVote setTitle:@"Vote" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Also, you should set the frames in `layoutSubviews`, not `init…`.